# How to access/initialize and update values in a mutable map?

Tags: scala, dictionary

Consider the simple problem of using a mutable map to keep track of occurrences/counts, i.e. with:

```
val counts = collection.mutable.Map[SomeKeyType, Int]()
```

My current approach to incrementing a count is:

```
counts(key) = counts.getOrElse(key, 0) + 1
// or equivalently
counts.update(key, counts.getOrElse(key, 0) + 1)
```

This somehow feels a bit clumsy, because I have to specify the key twice. In terms of performance, I would also expect that `key` has to be located twice in the map, which I would like to avoid. Interestingly, this access and update problem would not occur if `Int` would provide some mechanism to modify itself. Changing from `Int` to a `Counter` class that provides an `increment` function would for instance allow:

```
// not possible with Int
counts.getOrElseUpdate(key, 0) += 1
// but with a modifiable counter
counts.getOrElseUpdate(key, new Counter).increment
```

Somehow I'm always expecting to have the following functionality with a mutable map (somewhat similar to `transform` but without returning a new collection and on a specific key with a default value):

```
// fictitious use
counts.updateOrElse(key, 0, _ + 1)
// or alternatively
counts.getOrElseUpdate(key, 0).modify(_ + 1)
```

However as far as I can see, such a functionality does not exist. Wouldn't it make sense in general (performance and syntax wise) to have such a `f: A => A` in-place modification possibility? Probably I'm just missing something here... I guess there must be some better solution to this problem making such a functionality unnecessary?

**Update:**

I should have clarified that I'm aware of `withDefaultValue` but the problem remains the same: performing two lookups is still *twice* as slow than one, no matter if it is a O(1) operation or not. Frankly, in many situations I would be more than happy to achieve a speed-up of factor 2. And obviously the construction of the modification closure can often be moved outside of the loop, so imho this is not a big issue compared to running an operation unnecessarily twice.

Comment: Key lookup in a standard Map should usually be O(1), so there's not a big penalty in looking it up twice - probably less than is paid by constructing the closure for the function to pass into `updateOrElse`.

Comment: @Impredicative: That's a good point in this example. But the functionality in the trait itself does not make any assumption on that. For instance, `Map` is also implemented by `TreeMap` and `ListMap` which are O(log N) and O(N) respectively. So without making an O(1) assumption, in-place modification would still be desirable in general.

Comment: I'm with you, bluenote10 -- I was sure there would be something like `map.update(key, initValue) { <update func> }` because it performs substantially better *and* is cleaner.  If performance didn't matter, we probably wouldn't be using a mutable Map in the first place.  And as mentioned in another comment, `(_+1)` is *not* a closure, since it does not close over any free variables -- there is nothing to construct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, [`Map#updateWith`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#updateWith(key:K)(remappingFunction:Option[V]=%3EOption[V]):Option[V]) serves this exact purpose:

```
map.updateWith("a")({
  case Some(count) => Some(count + 1)
  case None        => Some(1)
})
```

> def updateWith(key: K)(remappingFunction: (Option[V]) => Option[V]): Option[V]

---

For instance, if the key doesn't exist:

```
val map = collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]()
// map: collection.mutable.Map[String, Int] = HashMap()

map.updateWith("a")({ case Some(count) => Some(count + 1) case None => Some(1) })
// Option[Int] = Some(1)
map
// collection.mutable.Map[String, Int] = HashMap("a" -> 1)
```

and if the key exists:

```
map.updateWith("a")({ case Some(count) => Some(count + 1) case None => Some(1) })
// Option[Int] = Some(2)
map
// collection.mutable.Map[String, Int] = HashMap("a" -> 2)
```

Answer (score 29):

You could create the map with a default value, which would allow you to do the following:

```
scala> val m = collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map()

scala> m.update("a", m("a") + 1)

scala> m
res6: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
```

As Impredicative mentioned, map lookups are fast so I wouldn't worry about 2 lookups.

**Update:**

As Debilski pointed out you can do this even more simply by doing the following:

```
scala> val m = collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
scala> m("a") += 1
scala> m
 res6: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
```

Comment: Note that `m("a") += 1` is sugar(^) for `m("a") = m("a") + 1` is sugar for `m.update("a", m("a") + 1)`. (^ or rather sugar by convention, as the `+=` method possibly implemented directly on `mutable.Map`)

Comment: I was aware of the default value approach but unfortunately I forgot to mention it in my question. I did not consider it here since my actual concern (the double lookup) is not solved with this approach. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. Creating the closure (or any function call) would be worse in terms of performance than 2 Map lookups for HashMap.

Comment: @coltfred: Are you really sure about that? I just had a quick glance at how `mutable.HashMap` is implemented. The lookup itself calls `findEntry` from `HashTable`, which again calls `findEntry0`  (involving a while loop to deal with collisions) and the `index` function. The `index` calculation seems lightweight but also contains a function call to `bitCount`. I'm wondering: Since a lookup itself involves several function calls, how could it be faster than calling a function like `def f(x: Int) = x + 1`? I'm even not so sure whether the lookup in total can be faster than creating a closure.

Comment: I forgot all about this question.  I shouldn't have spoken in such strong terms. I should know better than to make *any* statement about JVM performance without testing it first. In short, no I'm not *sure*. :)

Comment: Just to be clear, (_+1) is not a closure, because it doesn't close over any free variables.  No object gets created for it at the call site; it's just a reference to a function that was created once and for all during initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to lazy-initialise my mutable map instead of doing a fold (for memory efficiency).  The **collection.mutable.Map.getOrElseUpdate()** method suited my purposes.  My map contained a mutable object for summing values (again, for efficiency).

```
        val accum = accums.getOrElseUpdate(key, new Accum)
        accum.add(elem.getHours, elem.getCount)
```

*collection.mutable.Map.withDefaultValue()* does not keep the default value for a subsequent requested key.

Comment: Note that the question was especially addressing the case where `getOrElseUpdate` is not applicable (scalars), that is even the example I gave in the question. If you have mutable objects, that's the obvious choice.